# Spring Pageable implementation on SQL Server 2008 - Offset clause

Tags: sql-server, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying implement a paging and sorting repository with a @Query annotation.  The query is simple enough:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(B.batch), B.scanDate, COUNT(B.batchReferenceNumber) as TransactionCount FROM Batch B
```

My database is SQL Server.  The query that is getting generated is:

```
    select
    distinct batch0_.BatchNumber as col_0_0_,
    count(batch0_.BatchNumber) as col_8_0_ 
from
    BATCH batch0_ 
order by
    batch0_.BatchNumber asc offset ? rows fetch next ? rows only
```

I get an error:  Incorrect syntax near 'offset'.

The reason is "Offset" was not introduced until SQL Server 2012.

Is there any way around this?  Or do I need to implement my own repository versus using the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL for the offset/limit clause is generated by your JPA provider. 
You might be able to fix this by configuring the correct `SqlDialect` or if no such dialect is available you may raise an issue with that project.

Comment: That was perfect.  I changed the dialect to 2008 and it works now.  I was even able to get rid of the @Query annotation and use straight JPQL.